# PHP Regex: not wrapped items

Tags: php, regex

How i can find and replace all non-wrapped items in string via PHP regular expression?

For example, I have source string "2a{2}b2ac1{1}a{2}aab12{1}b2a{1}2" and try find symbol "2", which are not covered by "{" and "}", after this replace it with "{3}":

```
$input_lines = "2a{2}b2ac1{1}a{2}aab12{1}b2a{1}2";
$regex = "/[^\{](2)[^\}]/";
$input_lines = preg_replace("/[^\{](2)[^\}]/", "{3}", $input_lines);
echo $input_lines;
// 2a{2}{3}c1{1}a{2}aab{3}1}{3}{1{3}
```

How you can see, it's now work :(

Comment: To clarify: you want `123` to turn to `1{3}2`, but nothing should happen to `1{2}3`..correct?

Comment: @SamSullivan, "123" turn to "1{3}3" and nothing happen with 1{2}3. Just replace all "2" into "{3}", but don't replace "{2}".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`/(?<!{)2(?!})/`](http://regex101.com/r/mR0bA2) will do the trick.  Updated to take care of scenarios like `123}`.

```
$input_lines = '2a{2}b2ac1{1}a{2}aab12{1}b2a{1}2';
$input_lines = preg_replace('/(?<!{)2(?!})/', '{3}', $input_lines);

var_dump($input_lines);
// string(42) "{3}a{2}b{3}ac1{1}a{2}aab1{3}{1}b{3}a{1}{3}"
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                                 # Beginning delimiter
 (?<!{)                           # Lookbehind for anything other than {
  2                               # Match 2
 (?!})                            # Lookahead for anything other than }
/                                 # Ending delimiter
```

Comment: No problem, please select if it works. Also checkout some information on [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). If you need an explanation of my RegEx, I can provide.

Comment: This logic is wrong. It matches `2` that is not followed by `{`. He's asking for `2` that is not `{2}`, which is different.

Comment: Yes, I will check you answer as right. But I can do it only after few minuter(stackoverflow site system lock)...

Comment: Fixed @EdCottrell. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @Sam Sullivan Your first answer was wrong... and then you copy/paste mine... Not nice... :P Anyhow this is just for fun, so it does not matter :)

Comment: @Gooseman my first answer was wrong.  But I didn't copy yours..just moved my `{` into a negative lookahead based off of @EdCottrell's comment.  Yes it ends up being the same RegEx, which is why I decided to add an explanation.  Anyways, no worries tis all for fun.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
$input_lines = preg_replace('/(?<!{)2(?!})/', '{3}', $input_lines);
```